# Unity 2d how to stop infinite jump

Tags: unity, physics

So my problem is very common but as far I am able to find tutorial on how to stop game object to do infinite jump is make a bool then set  if y velocity == 0  then set bool to true else its false but doing this makes object movement very jittery , so what is most efficient and pro ways= to make object stop jumping infinitely?

I m using Rigidbody2d not CC so isgrounded is not applicable

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    Vector2 velocity = box.velocity;
    velocity.x = Xvelocity;
    box.velocity = velocity;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    Vector2 velocity = box.velocity;
    velocity.x = -Xvelocity;
    box.velocity = velocity;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    if (toJump)
    {
        Vector2 velocity = box.velocity;
        velocity.y = Yvelocity;
        box.velocity = velocity;
    }
}

if (box.velocity.y < 0f)
{
    Vector2 velocity = box.velocity;
    velocity.y = -gravity;
    box.velocity = velocity;
}
if(box.velocity.y == 0f)
{
    toJump = true;
}
else
{
    toJump = false;
}
```

Comment: Your jump code sounds very, very wrong. Incidentally, I ran across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KiK0Aqtmzc) recently on how to do a better jump in 4 lines of code.

Comment: @Draco18s I watched this video it's very good for making better and Mario like jump but it didn't show how to stop infinite jump

Comment: I don't know what's causing your infinite jump, you haven't posted any code or explained what's wrong.

Comment: @Draco18s i added the code the left and jump become so jittery

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, a few things:

1) You should be using `Input.GetButton()` and `Input.GetButtonDown()`, this allows players to modify their keybindings (what if they want to use IJKL instead of WASD?)

2) This code:

```
if (box.velocity.y < 0f)
{
    Vector2 velocity = box.velocity;
    velocity.y = -gravity;
    box.velocity = velocity;
}
```

This doesn't make sense. If the player's falling (velocity y is negative) you set their velocity to `negative gravity` which is either going to make them go up again (which is not good) or is going to replace their downward velocity--whatever it is--*with* a gravitational speed, making their fall *linear* (also not good). In either case you're enforcing this instead of letting the physics engine Do Its Thing.

3) y-velocity of 0 is not indicative of being grounded. At the top of the player's jump, y-velocity will *also* be zero.  And this is ignoring the problem of [floating point values hardly ever equaling anything](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm). You should be using some kind of raycast or overlap check to see if your character is standing on something instead.

4) It is unclear if this code is in `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()` (it should probably be in the latter)

5) You should probably be using [`MovePosition()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) for your left/right walking code.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Draco's answer a little bit, when using a Rigidbody of any kind (2D or otherwise) it tends to be better practice to use the built in Physics functions, such as [Rigidbody2D.AddForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) and [Physics2D.Raycast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) in this case which is basically the two main functions used by the Character Controller Asset.

In the case of stopping "Infinite Jump" using a Raycast will do the trick.
The following function can be called whenever the character attempt to jump, it will return true if the ground is under the character and false if not allowing for it to only jump when it hits the ground. Make sure to put this check within `FixedUpdate()` as it is a physics function.

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if the Character is Grounded using a Raycast. Passing the Distance from the Center of the Character and the tag name of the ground
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rayDistance"></param>
/// <param name="groundLayerName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool IsGrounded2D(float rayDistance, string groundLayerName)
{
    //Can be used to visualize the Ray from scene view
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -Vector2.up * rayDistance, Color.red);

    //Use a Raycast down from the Character to find any object of the Ground Layer
    //This also requires the distance from where the ray starts to the bottom of the Character
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, rayDistance);

    if (hit.collider && hit.collider.tag == groundLayerName)
        //If it hits, return true
        return true;

    //else return false
    return false;
}
```

This requires the ground to have a tag on it you can parse to the function to detect the correct object. Alternatively you could use Layer detection within the `Raycast` but its really up to you.

Remember that this will work for detecting `Collider2D` components, if you want to detect a 3D object your will be required to change it to do `RaycastHit` and `Physics.Raycast` instead.

As a bit of a side note from the question. When using the Rigidbody it would be better to use something similar to the following in order to control the left and right movement of the character, this will allow for it to be used in both a PC and Controller environment by using force and input which will not add any jitter to the movement.

```
[RequireComponent (typeof(Motor))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Motor motor;

    private void Start()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<Motor>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        motor.HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }
}

[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Motor : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public float jumpForce;

private float horizontalInput;
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

private void Start()
{
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Use Fixed Update for Physics Math
/// </summary>
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Add a force depending on the input value (Between -1 for left an 1 for right) and times it by the required character speed.
    //This will allow the User to ramp up their own speed with a controller but also allow the character to slow itself down.
    rigidBody.AddForce((Vector2.right * horizontalInput) * speed);

    //Check if the character is grounded
    if (IsGrounded2D(0.5f, "Ground"))
    {
        //Add Force to make the character jump
        rigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Check if the Character is Grounded using a Raycast. Passing the Distance from the Center of the Character and the tag name of the ground
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rayDistance"></param>
/// <param name="groundLayerName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool IsGrounded2D (float rayDistance, string groundLayerName)
{
    //Can be used to visualize the Ray from scene view
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -Vector2.up * rayDistance, Color.red);

    //Use a Raycast down from the Character to find any object of the Ground Layer
    //This also requires the distance from where the ray starts to the bottom of the Character
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, rayDistance);

    if (hit.collider && hit.collider.tag == groundLayerName)
        //If it hits, return true
        return true;

    //else return false
    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Set the Horizontal Input and Clamp it between -1 for left and 1 for right
/// </summary>
public float HorizontalInput
{
    get
    {
        return horizontalInput;
    }

    set
    {
        horizontalInput = Mathf.Clamp(value, -1, 1);
    }
}
```

This typically requires you to split your `Character` script into a `Motor` and `Character` script as the `Motor` just controls any movement whilst the `Character` tells it what to do (useful if you want to get into AI).

Sorry about the long answer and maybe some unneeded information just a bit of a tip.